# Haskell Beam Subquery without aggregation

Tags: haskell, haskell-beam

I am trying to apply Haskell Beam library in my project and I would like to write a select with subqueries, but without aggregation.

e.g.

```
select
  (select * from t order by ts desc limit 1),
  (select * from t order by ts asc limit 1),
  (select count(*) from t)
```

I found an example for aggregating subquery, but no the case above. I found `subselect_` function, but there is no docs for it nor an example.